# Gradle GitHub Dependency plugin not finding dependencies

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I configured a GitHub workflow to collect & submit the Gradle dependencies using `gradle-build-action`, which in turn uses `github-dependency-graph-gradle-plugin`. For some repos this worked just fine, but for one repo it found nothing. I'm expecting to see the javafx dependencies listed. How do I troubleshoot this?

This repo is running Gradle v 8.2.1

Here is the pertinent part of the GitHub workflow:

```yaml
      - name: Setup Gradle to generate and submit dependency graphs
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          dependency-graph: generate-and-submit

      - name: Run a build, generating the dependency graph from 'runtimeClasspath' configurations
        run: ./gradlew build --exclude-task test
        env:
          DEPENDENCY_GRAPH_INCLUDE_CONFIGURATIONS: runtimeClasspath
```

This is the output from `.\gradlew touchtime:dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath`:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Project ':touchtime'
------------------------------------------------------------

runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- org.openjfx:javafx-base:15
+--- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:15
|    \--- org.openjfx:javafx-base:15
+--- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:15
|    \--- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:15 (*)
+--- org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:15
|    \--- org.openjfx:javafx-controls:15 (*)
+--- org.openjfx:javafx-swing:15
|    \--- org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:15 (*)
+--- org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.12
\--- org.openjfx:javafx:15.0.1
```

And this is the resulting JSON file from the dependency plugin:

```json
{
  "version" : 0,
  "job" : {
    "id" : "5977018633",
    "correlator" : "dependencies-depend-submit"
  },
  "sha" : "7c7f4c854a2a5129ff0776b017b6838d20cd9c61",
  "ref" : "refs/heads/main",
  "detector" : {
    "name" : "GitHub Dependency Graph Gradle Plugin",
    "version" : "0.2.0",
    "url" : "https://github.com/gradle/github-dependency-graph-gradle-plugin"
  },
  "manifests" : {
    "dependencies-depend-submit" : {
      "name" : "dependencies-depend-submit",
      "resolved" : { },
      "file" : {
        "source_location" : "settings.gradle"
      }
    }
  },
  "scanned" : "2023-08-25T14:21:33Z"
}
```

And in case it helps, here is the `build.gradle` script:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
}

javafx {
    version = '15'
    modules = ['javafx.base', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.controls',
               'javafx.graphics', 'javafx.swing'
    ]
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

configurations {
    extraLibs
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.12'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx:15.0.1'
    implementation files('dist/Classes.jar')

    extraLibs group: 'org.controlsfx', name: 'controlsfx', version: '8.40.12'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.3'
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.9.3")

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:5.4.0'
}

tasks.withType(Jar).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    doLast {
        new File("$buildDir/baseVersion.txt").text = gradle.ext.baseVersion
        new File("$buildDir/deployVersion.txt").text = gradle.ext.deployVersion
    }
}

jar {
    compileJava.options.debugOptions.debugLevel = "source,lines,vars"

    //Build MANIFEST.MF
    manifest {
        attributes 'Built-By' : System.properties['user.name']
        attributes 'Build-Timestamp': new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(new Date())
        attributes 'Created-By' : "Gradle ${gradle.gradleVersion}"
        attributes 'Build-Jdk' : "${System.properties['java.version']} (${System.properties['java.vendor']} ${System.properties['java.vm.version']})"
        attributes 'Manifest-Version': gradle.ext.baseVersion
        attributes 'Deploy-Package': gradle.ext.deployVersion
        attributes 'Main-Class': gradle.ext.mainClass
    }

    // Add controlsFX Source Files into JAR output
    from {
        configurations.extraLibs.collect{
            it.isDirectory() ? it: zipTree(it)
        }
    }

    // Set output to dist/App.jar
    archiveBaseName.set("App")
    destinationDirectory.set(file("$rootDir/touchtime/dist"))
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Is the repository private? Could you share it? Are you sure its Gradle 8.2? Plugin mentiones something that if you have configuration cache enabled it might produce empty dependency graph https://github.com/gradle/github-dependency-graph-gradle-plugin#gradle-compatibility

Comment: The repo is private, unfortunately. Yes, I can confirm it is running **Gradle 8.2.1** as listed in the GitHub action summary created by gradle-build-action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @albciff approach, I found that removing the option
`DEPENDENCY_GRAPH_INCLUDE_CONFIGURATIONS: runtimeClasspath` started producing results in the JSON output file. I cannot explain why this was needed for this repo when other repos seem to work, but for now it is producing the dependencies and submitting them to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

It only starts to work, when the `--exclude-task test` in the `gradle` call it's removed.

TL;DR;

I make some tries using different `gradle-build-action` versions (v2, v2.8.0, v2.5.0 etc), trying with the different `dependency-graph:` values (generate, generate-and-submit ...), specifying `gradle-version`, adding `cache-disabled : true`.

Trying also specifying different gradle versions in `gradle.wrapper` instead of `gradle-version` parameter, adding `--no-configuration-cache --no-build-cache` parametres in the `run: gradlew`.

Nothing change in the workflow assert output, which is not generating the dependency-graph, until `--exclude-task` it's removed (note that `-x` parameter to exclude a task produce the same effect). I cannot explain why this happens, but this works for me:

```
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
    - name: Run chmod to make gradlew executable
      run: chmod +x ./gradlew
    - name: Setup Gradle to generate and submit dependency graphs
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2.8.0
      with:
        gradle-version: 8.2.1
        #cache-disabled: true
        dependency-graph: generate
    - run: ./gradlew build
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however when I removed the `--exclude-task test` option the resulting JSON still does not include any dependencies. I will experiment with changing other options and see if I can get any different results.